# Neo4j 4.0 Spring how to specify database?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

With neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter 4.0.0, is there a way to specify which database the Neo4jRepository is going against? NOTE: I am speaking of multiple database support in the 4.0 preview, NOT the Uri.

There seems to be a session() on the Driver where I can specify a SessionForDatabase, but I'm not sure how to use that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SDN 4 does not support the multi-database feature of Neo4j 4.

The OGM has just upgraded to the latest Bolt driver but I don't see support right now for specifying another database (or I missed it). So once this happens, it should be available in the corresponding SDN release (which is 5+, not 4)

Comment: I see support for it on driver.session(SessionConfig.forDatabase(""))...?

Comment: Yes, on Neo4j's Bolt driver. But it has to be exposed via the OGM Session